# Mailchimp api v3 - add member to list with merge_fields

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I send this object as HTTP POST:

```
{
    "email_address": "rickard@transticket.se",
    "status": "subscribed",
    "merge_fields": {
        "APA": "1",
        "HEJ": "2"
    }
}
```

to `https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/045dfc0a43/members`

and I got this response:

```
{
    "type": "http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
    "title": "Invalid Resource",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.",
    "instance": "",
    "errors": [ {
        "field": "",
        "message": "Schema describes object, array found instead"
    }]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: check your list merge fields dose it have APA and HEJ

Answer (score 3):

I would have preferred to post a comment but I am still lacking in SO rep pts.

My short answer would be, without more information on the code you're using, that the error means that you have not passed a properly 'set' `JSON` object to the API. It will be good to remember that even though you have set it as a JSON object initially, you must be sure that the name-value pairs in your `"merge_fields"` must also be a `JSON` object.

However, if you're certain that the main and inner name-value pairs were indeed both set in JSON correctly, kindly post the code and I will try to help more.

Comment: Yes, i have taked many looks on this and it is a json object, now i found some other wrapper that working with other type of client and its works so going to not use my own code more i think.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy and your code POST request is right. Maybe the Merge fields don't exist in your list. The *merge_fields* parameter takes a dict with some pre-defined keys. See below.

```
{
    apikey: "yourmailmergekey"
    email_address: "test_email@gmail.com"
    status: "subscribed"
    merge_fields: {
        "FNAME: "-- First Name --",
        "LNAME": "-- Last Name --",
        "PHONE": "-- Phone Number --",
        "ADDRESS": "-- Address --"
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

this code be working for me.

```
{
  "email_address": "test_email@gmail.com",
  "status": "subscribed",
  "merge_fields": {
    "FNAME": "teste",
    "LNAME": "92988410440"
  }
}
```

[image]
link helpful - https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/create-your-first-audience/