# Mailchimp API Put or Patch using Delphi REST

Tags: rest, delphi, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have a program that can connect to mailchimp via the API and download the data, I now need to be able to update certain email addresses and add new ones.  Within the Mailchimp layout I have a custom Merge field called

MMMERGE6 which is a text field.

I need to be able to update this field with a new value.

I have tried building the request in the REST Debugger and although the rest debugger returns no errors the update does not seem to happen.  I found an article somewhere on stackoverflow that said that there is an issue with mailchimp to do with where the post content needs to be and if its in the wrong place it fails.

I have code as follows but I am now very stuck.

```
unit mailud;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, REST.Types, Vcl.StdCtrls, REST.Client,
  REST.Authenticator.Basic, Data.Bind.Components, Data.Bind.ObjectScope;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
    RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
    RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
    HTTPBasicAuthenticator1: THTTPBasicAuthenticator;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

(* For Visibility

RESTRequest1.baseurl:='https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/dc2af4377f/members/c266cac4b1560b2e88cc893a9a0a1d2c';

*)

(* Trying to Update the Content of Merge_Fields MMERGE6 which is a JSON OBJECT *)
(*  Code from REST Debugger Returns No Errors but update fails *)
(* Note on Stackexchange mentions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388838/mailchimp-api-v3-add-member-to-list-with-merge-fields
*)

RESTRequest1.Method := TRestRequestMethod.rmPUT;
RESTRequest1.Params[0].Value:='{merge_fields: {"MMERGE6":  "99999999"}}';
RESTRequest1.AddBody('{merge_fields: {"MMERGE6":  "99999999"}}');
restrequest1.Execute;


end;

end.
```

Any help would be appreciated.
THanks
Phil

Answer (score 1):

I tried this again today and changed the request to a Put request.

```
mystring:='{ "merge_fields": { "MMERGE6":  "39999999"  } }';




restrequest1.Body.Add(mystring);
restrequest1.Execute;
```

I also double quoted the variable names as well and it now works !

I have not tried doing as a put as this achieves my desired result of allowing me to update a record and also insert a new one.